# Run a shell to check directory exist on the list of servers and get output in a file

Tags: shell

I have the mentioned script which can check the existence of directory in Linux servers. I could check the directory exist but i want to run this on a list of servers saved in txt file and can gain the output as directory exist or not in an txt file. Please suggest!!

```
   #!/bin/bash 
if [ -d /vat/opt/BESClient ]; 
then 
    echo "The Directory Exists"
else
    echo "The Directory is not present"
fi
```

Comment: `Please suggest!!` Then do it! Run the script on each of the servers from the list and redirect the output to a txt file.

Comment: Cant i save the list of servers in a file and use the file in the script to get the output rather running on each server?

Comment: `Cant i save the list of servers in a file and use the file in the script to get the output rather running on each server?` Sure, yes. Sky's the limit. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), check [questions checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). If you are having a specific problem with your script, please post what have you tried and how does it fail, ie. post an [MCVE]. And before you do, check it with http://shellcheck.net . If you ask if something "can be done" the answer is "yes".

Comment: Be sure to learn the shell and bash, read [bashfaq how to read a file line by line field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Pro tip: with simple commands as such, you can just naturally do `if ssh server [ -d /vat/opt/BESClient ]; then`.

Comment: Sure thing and Thank you KamilCuk!!